# I get an error, but my program works and behaves as expected. Just an unwanted error message at end

Tags: python, python-3.x, literals, divide

```
f = open("arvud.txt", "r")
arv = f.readline()
arv = arv.strip()

while arv != " ":
    if int(arv)%2 > 0:
        print("Arv " + str(arv) + " on paaritu arv.")
    else:
        print("Arv " + str(arv) + " on paarisarv.")
    arv = f.readline()
    arv = arv.strip()
```

This is my code, and it works to find out if the number divides by 2 or not. It reads numbers from a file in each line.

arvud.txt

```
10
2
1
6
17
36665
1000000001
25832864968
```

This is what it looks like in IDLE.

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Arv 10 on paarisarv.
Arv 2 on paarisarv.
Arv 1 on paaritu arv.
Arv 6 on paarisarv.
Arv 17 on paaritu arv.
Arv 36665 on paaritu arv.
Arv 1000000001 on paaritu arv.
Arv 25832864968 on paarisarv.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\9.veebruar\2. kodutöö\1paarispaaritu.py", line 8, in <module>
    if int(arv)%2 > 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

I need to add more text... grrhh. I just need help on how to bypass this. I am new to this program and I would really like some help with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the file, `f.readline()` will return an empty string. Therefore, you should test for an empty string:

```
while arv:
```

rather than testing against `arv != " "`.